# NEO4J performance excuting query multiple times

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a neo4j graph that is composed by Serie as nodes and EDGE as relationships. I have a query that is able to calculate allShortestaPaths between two nodes.

```
MATCH (serie1:Serie {serie_id: 'id1'}),
      (serie2:Serie {serie_id: 'id2'}), 
      p = allShortestPaths((serie1)-[EDGE*..6]-(serie2)) 
RETURN p as shortestPath
```

My application is making several iterations, on each iteration it execute the query multiple times with two different nodes (serie1,serie2), and then writes some new EDGES on the graph.

The first iteration (20 queries) are executed very fast, but on second iteration the response time starts to increase and the query takes more than 3 minutes on every execution.

I've created index on serie_id property, and I also increase the heap space until 8GB of space, and the Page Cache Sizing has also been enabled with enough space.

I've also was investigating if the query can be rewrited in other way, but it seems that this is the better way.

I guess that the problem is related with the number of executions, but not sure on how to optimize it.

Comment: what version of neo4j do you use ?

Comment: Are you able to `PROFILE` one of the queries before and after the first iteration, to compare the results?

Comment: Im using neo4j version 3.6

Comment: here is the result of execution after one execution but before starting to hang https://gist.github.com/silvestrelosada/9f91bbb94da01b0c3c57494e7b4bd973

Answer (score 0):

> My application is making several iterations, on each iteration it
>   execute the query multiple times with two different nodes
>   (serie1,serie2), and then writes some new EDGES on the graph.

If the new writes affect the `paths` or the `nodes` being matched during the iterations, you might encounter the query sampling marking your query as stale after x number of times.

I would suggest you check the `logs/debug.log` file if you see such lines :

```
2016-09-22 09:32:39.178+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.a.i.s.OnlineIndexSamplingJob] Sampled index :WithIndex(id) with 1001 unique values in sample of avg size 1001 taken from index containing 1001 entries
2016-09-22 09:32:49.179+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.a.i.s.OnlineIndexSamplingJob] Sampled index :WithIndex(id) with 1001 unique values in sample of avg size 1001 taken from index containing 1001 entries

AND

2016-09-22 07:26:01.359+0000 INFO  [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache: CREATE (n:Node {id: {i} })
2016-09-22 07:26:01.361+0000 INFO  [o.n.c.i.CypherCompiler] Discarded stale query from the query cache: CREATE (n:Node {id: {i} })
2016-09-22 07:26:10.403+0000 INFO  [o.n.c.i.ExecutionEngine] Discarded stale query from the query cache: CREATE (n:Node {id: {i} })
2016-09-22 07:26:10.404+0000 INFO  [o.n.c.i.CypherCompiler] Discarded stale query from the query cache: CREATE (n:Node {id: {i} })
```

Of course those lines reflect the queries I do in my application, your queries should appear instead. You can also see GC pauses during those logs.

You can tune the treshold to which queries are considered as stale. The setting is described here :

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/#config_cypher.statistics_divergence_threshold

and here

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/#config_cypher.min_replan_interval

There is no out-of-the box value, I would increase the first one to 0.8 maybe but it is not easy as it can affect other queries.

Comment: I see some queries marking as stale, but those queries are not taking too much time 
Discarded stale query from the query cache: MATCH (serie:Serie{serie_id: 'serieie1'}) RETURN count(*).

I think that the issue is related with Garbage collector. There is a lot of logs like this

2016-09-27 16:20:01.946+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 78198ms.
2016-09-27 16:21:22.061+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 79705ms.

Comment: Are you creating new "Serie" nodes during the writes ? As Frank suggested also please update your question with the initial profile and the query you are executing for writing the new data also.

Comment: During writes series are not created. Here is the queries that I'm using for creation.

MATCH (serie1:Serie{serie_id='id1')
MATCH (serie2:Serie{serie_id='id2')
MERGE (serie1)-[:EDGE {weight:10 ,potential:3}]->(serie2)

Comment: I have one doubt, regarding with commit. I'm using jdbctemplate.update(statement) to create the edges. How neo4j is managing the commits? is it automatically committing the information after update method?